# Dart, conditional loading of Angular 2 packages/modules

Tags: angular, dart, dart2js

Can output of dart2js (and angular2) be split into multiple packages and conditionally loaded during app runtime?

Similar to how RequireJS can do conditional loading of app parts/packages.

Example:

```
<button onClick="showAdminInterface()">ADMIN</button>

function showAdminInterface()
{
     require(['myApp/AdminPackage'], function(pkg){
         pkg.display();
     });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart supports lazy loading of libraries and Angular2 also allows to use this feature.

For details see

- https://medium.com/@matanlurey/lazy-loading-with-angular-dart-14f58004f988#.fgko6q5aq
- http://news.dartlang.org/2014/08/dart-16-adds-support-for-deferred.html

Comment: Excellent, deferred loading is exactly what im looking for.